# Как создать телеграм бота, чтобы он в ответ на запрос пользователя присылал информацию из базы данных в соответствии с запросом?

Tags: python, mysql, база-данных, telegram-bot, google-apps-script

Есть задача: нужно создать телеграмм-бота, который будет присылать домохозяйке данные (например рецепты) из базы данных по соответствующему её запросу. Сделать нужно для её удобства, чтобы когда ей понадобится какой-то рецепт, не лезть в интернет, книги или делать звонок другу, а, поскольку телефон всегда при себе - обращаться к своему боту, чтобы он присылал рецепт. Стоит отметить, что есть некоторые рецепты, которые она держит в секрете, то есть создавать публичный контент с рецептами в её случае не подойдет.
Насколько я понимаю, можно это сделать разными путями. Написать бота через python, и через sql подключить базу рецептов. Но тут есть неудобство, поскольку домохозяйке будет сложно объяснить, как делать новые записи в бд, чтобы всё работало. Есть вариант сделать через гугл таблицы с помощью Apps Scripts. Этот вариант предпочтительнее, поскольку она сама сможет править свои рецепты, добавлять, удалять и т.д.
То есть пользователь вводит какое-то сообщение боту (например, "торт"), бот ищет в определенной колонке строку в таблице, где есть слово "торт", переходит в нужную колонку и возвращает обратно пользователю содержание той ячейки (например рецепт торта). Если введёт "компот", то вернет рецепт компота и так далее.. То есть по сути пользователь вводит своеборазный id строки, а в ответ получает содержание определенной ячейки, соответствующее этому id.
В сети делал соответствующие запросы, и пока не попадалось примера, как можно получать содержание определенной ячейки из бд по соответствующему запросу. Подскажите, пожалуйста, реализуемо ли это? И если да, то что почитать/посмотреть?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Да, реализуемо. Почитать: - программирование на Python - работа с базами данных - сетевое взаимодействие - основы SQL

Comment: Есть задача, должен быть и исполнитель. Контакты при желании можно найти в два клика.